# Getting data not according to the same order that I call those methods in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have aded [HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl) to make a swiping segmented control in my iOS app.I am loading all the data initially because then it will facilitate the scrolling. So I have to load several tables under several categories. Category name is the segmented control item title. So this is how I set my titles.

```
for(var i=0; i<dm.TableData.count; i++)
    {
       self.array.append(dm.TableData[i]["name"] as! String)

    }
segmentedControl.sectionTitles=self.array
```

Categories are loading according to the order of this array without any issue. Then I am loading my tables like this.

```
for i in 0..<dm.TableData.count {

        self.catID=self.dm.TableData[i]["term_id"] as? String

        switch self.catID {

        case "55":
            self.jsonParser()

        case "1":
            self.getBusiness()
        case "2":
            self.getNews()
        case "4":
            self.getSports()
        case "5":
            self.getEntertainment()
        case "57":
            self.getCrime()
        case "21":
            self.getPolitics()
        case "28":
            self.getWorld()
        case "89":
            self.getVideos()
        case "111":
            self.getLocalNews()

        default:
            print("Default")
        }




        }
```

This is my jsonParser method. `getBusiness()`,`getNews()`,`getSports()` all those methods are just same as this and load to seperate array and the dictionary key is different.

```
func jsonParser() {



    let urlPath = "http://www.li67t8.lk/mobileapp/news.php?"
    let category_id=self.catID
    let catParam="category_id"
    let strCatID="\(catParam)=\(category_id)"

    let strStartRec:String=String(startRec)
    let startRecPAram="start_record_index"
    let strStartRecFull="\(startRecPAram)=\(strStartRec)"


    let strNumOfRecFull="no_of_records=10"

    let fullURL = "\(urlPath)\(strCatID)&\(strStartRecFull)&\(strNumOfRecFull)"
    print(fullURL)


    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: fullURL) else {
        print("Error creating endpoint")
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:endpoint)
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }
           print(json)


            if let countries_list = json["data"] as? NSArray
            {

               // for (var i = 0; i < countries_list.count ; i++ )
                    for i in 0..<countries_list.count
                {
                    if let country_obj = countries_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        //self.TableData.append(country_obj)
                        self.breakingNews.append(country_obj)


                    }
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("%%%%%%%%%%% CAT ID %%%%%%%%%% \(self.catID)")


                    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: self.breakingNews[0]["thumb_url"] as! String) {
                        self.imageURL=checkedUrl
                    }

                    if let time = self.breakingNews[0]["duration"] as? String
                    {
                        self.timeDuration=time
                    }

                    if let likes = self.breakingNews[0]["read_count"] as? String
                    {
                        self.noOfLikes=likes
                    }

                    if let title = self.breakingNews[0]["post_title"] as? String
                    {
                        self.titleNews=title
                    }

                    self.addedArray.append("Breaking News")

                    self.commonData["Breaking News"]=self.breakingNews
                    self.updateUI()

                    print("-------BREAKING--------")

                }



            }

            } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
        }.resume()


}
```

I have one method for `UpdateUI()` and it creates `UITableView` dynamically and assign tag value dynamically (I keep an Int called index and I assign that index to tableview tag and after adding table to super view I increment the index count by 1)
According to this I get data and load to the tableview. But my problem is data not getting in the same order I call to those methods. As an example `jsonParser()` returns its data set and then it returns `getSportsData()` data. like wise my data not according to the segment title order.

So how can I solve this problem? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Because it is not synchronous request. May you did first request and your server response takes time and till you did second request and server respond second response quicker then first.

Comment: how can I change that in this case?

Comment: use nsoperation queue and and add dependency

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: for that, you need to read apple doc. Otherwise you can do by other way. You just add  "catID" in array. and do request one, after getting the response increase index and another request.